# Unable to create Table : Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Following is my spring-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.nm"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>


<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${dbdriverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db-url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db-username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db-password}"/>
    <!-- <property name="initialPoolSize" value="1" /> <property name="minPoolSize"
        value="1" /> <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" /> -->
</bean>


<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" >
        <list>
            <value>com.nm</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>



<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:property-files/config-info.properties"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

and persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="format_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and the snippet from the build.gradle containing the hibernate dependencies:

```
//hibernate dependenciess
compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.0.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.1.0.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:5.5.2.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.0.Final'
```

After the server starts up there aren't any table in database except for the table named `'hibernate_sequence'`. The entity is pasted below :

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

/**
 * Created by pallav on 15/4/16.
 */

@Entity
public class Tags {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String title;
private String seoTitle;
private String desc;
private String questions;
private short status;
- - -
```

Query found in the logs :

```
18:39:02.650 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'persistenceUnit' 
Hibernate: 
drop table if exists hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: 
drop table if exists Tags
Hibernate: 
create table hibernate_sequence (
    next_val bigint
) ENGINE=InnoDB
Hibernate: 
insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Hibernate: 
create table Tags (
    id bigint not null,
    createdDate datetime,
    desc varchar(255),
    questions varchar(255),
    seoTitle varchar(255),
    status smallint not null,
    title varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
18:39:04.618 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
```

Kindly help me out. Thanks

Comment: maybe the problem with the Dialect, try `MySQL5Dialect`

Answer (score 1):

Add your class in the `<persistence-unit>`

`<class>your.project.Tags</class>`

Answer (score 0):

You can add following property

```
<property name="packagesToScan">
    <list>
        <value>com.test.core.domain</value> //Replace this with the package where you have your domain entities.
        <value>...</value>
    </list>
<property>
```

to

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
```

for spring to autodetect your entities.

If you have all your entities in a single package, you can simplify it to

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test.core.domain" />
```

Comment: Still same probliem persists 'No Tags Table', I've updated the question.

Comment: @ObiWan-PallavJha I think after adding the above property your logs are indicating `create table Tags` DDL statement being executed. Are you getting any exception. If so can you show the exception stacktrace.

Comment: No, I'm not getting any exception.

Comment: @ObiWan-PallavJha Since the logs are indicating `create table Tags...`, I believe the table got created successfully. Can you try inserting a row in the Tag table through hibernate and see if that succeeds?

Answer (score 0):

[Obi Wan - PallavJha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2422530/obi-wan-pallavjha),

Why do you have a spring-config.xml AND a persistence.xml all with the same persistence information. It seems to me that there may be a conflict in the spring context container of identifying which of the 2 should be prioritized. In my opinion, remove one (likely the persistence.xml) and try to see if the problem still persists.